# Request.QueryString Collection return wrong result

Tags: vb.net, collections, request.querystring

I have query string that has parameters like that: ...&ChildAge=3&ChildAge=4
But collection return me result as "3,4" instead of 3 and 4, with this code:

```
 Dim a As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        For i = 0 To Request.QueryString("ChildAge").Count
            a.Add(Request.QueryString("ChildAge")(i))
        Next
```

What's wrong with it? How can I get separated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a `NameValueCollection`, therefore duplicate key values are concatenated as comma separated list (from the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsc9a449.aspx) method):

> If the specified key already exists in the target NameValueCollection
>   instance, the specified value is added to the existing comma-separated
>   list of values in the form **"value1,value2,value3"**.

You can use [`GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx) to retrieve a `string()` for a given key:

```
Dim childAges As String() = Request.QueryString.GetValues("ChildAge");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the parameter into an array of values, then you will be able to iterate through

```
myArray = Request.QueryString("ChildAge").Split(", ")
```

Comment: Well, seemed like this solution work, even if it's not exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
Dim a As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        For i = 0 To Request.QueryString("ChildAge").Count
            a.Add(Request.QueryString("ChildAge").Split(",")(i))
        Next
```